# How can one update a StringListProperty in GoogleAppEngine for Python?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I currently have an Events(db.Model) class as shown below:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    pw_hash = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.EmailProperty(required = True)
    position = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    signedevents = db.StringListProperty()
```

I have created an HTML file that derives a name of an event that will be appended to this StringListProperty. I wish to updated this StringListProperty for a specific user and not edit any of the other Properties. I understand that there is a method of Querying a specific username from an entity:

```
signeduser = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username=self.username")
```

I could potentially use this to update the signedevents Property for that specific user. However, I feel that this is grossly inefficient and most likely ineffective. What is the best way of updating a StringListProperty for an existing user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using the datastore.

You have get the entity. Update the specific StringList property of that entity and write the whole entity back to the datastore.

The fact you think that it is inefficient, wont' change the fact that is how the datastore works.

Now if this entity is big (lots of properties and indexes) which the model you have included above isn't, and you have lots of updates,   you might then consider splitting the model up into the frequently updates and infrequently updated parts, or the frequently used vs infrequently used properties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend using `ndb` instead of `db` for your models.  It will use memcache to save the entity in memory while writing to the datastore in the background.  Subsequent requests (by key) will be faster.

Second, take advantage of the [Property Options](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options) to make your datastore writes more efficient:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty('n', required = True)
    pw_hash = ndb.StringProperty('h', required = True, indexed = False)
    email = ndb.EmailProperty('e', required = True, indexed = False)
    position = ndb.StringProperty('p', required = True, indexed = False)
    signedevents = ndb.StringListProperty('e', indexed = False)
```

Use the first parameter to specify the property's name in the datastore, and add `indexed = False` to avoid updating extra indexes on each write (unless you need them indexed, of course).

Third, maybe use @timhoffman's suggestion to split out frequently updated values into another entity.  Create a one-to-one relationship between `User` and `SignedEvents` and update the StringListProperty independently.